# Create Github repository using command line + API

Tags: command-line, git, github, repository, api

Please provide working code that creates a Github repository using the API.

I have tried different versions of the following:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/users/repos?client_id= myusername&client_secret=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd'
curl -u 'myusername' https://api.github.com/users/repos -d '{"name":"my-new-repo"}'
```

But I always get the following error:

```
"{
  \"message\": \"Bad credentials\",
  \"documentation_url\": \"https://developer.github.com/v3\"
}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems in the `curl` commands you've posted:

- You're using the path `/users/repos`. **That will return the information of the user repos**, instead of modifying a user's repositories. You need to use `/user/repos` (delete the *s* from *users*).
- The field `client_secret` **isn't for your username**, but for the client ID you received when you [registered](https://github.com/settings/applications/new) your application in GitHub's API.
- Your `code` field is missing too, if you're using the Web Application Flow.

You can find more details on GitHub's API [OAuth section](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth).

However, if you're just looking for a ready-to-work version, this one worked for me:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" --data '{"name":"YOUR_REPO_NAME"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Although I'm pretty sure there are other simpler and cleaner ways to do this.

Comment: More details on getting the `token`: http://superuser.com/a/1069606/471181

Answer (score 4):

One clarification on @Hewbot's answer.

One can use *personal access tokens* instead of *OAuth*.

The `YOUR_TOKEN` value in the `"Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN"` section of the `curl` command can be obtained as follows.

1. Upper right corner, click <kbd>User</kbd>
2. <kbd>Settings</kbd>
3. <kbd>Personal Access Tokens</kbd>
4. For scopes, select <kbd>Repos</kbd>.
5. <kbd>Create New Token</kbd>.

For more details, [click here](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) and [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication).

Answer (score 3):

This might help someone out.

If you use a restful client with a GUI, this is basically the configuration that you need to get your repo created:

[image]

Make sure you add your token after the word token.